# Get the HTML Class Name inside Partial View in JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following markup inside my `.cshtml` Partial View and it is placed in the `Views/Shared` folder:

**_Modal.cshtml**

```
<div class="loadingOverlay">
    <button class="btn loading-button" disabled><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-2x fa-fw"></i></button>
</div>
```

And also the External JavaScript (different file from the Partial View .cshtml):

**Modal.js**

```
var Modal;

Modal = Modal || (function () {
    var loadingDiv = $('.loadingOverlay');
    return {
        Loading: function () {
            loadingDiv.css('display', 'block');
            $('body').prepend(loadingDiv);
        },
        LoadingDismiss: function () {
            loadingDiv.fadeOut('500');
        },
    };
})();
```

And I call from my page like below:

**Index.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/font-awesome", "~/Content/css")
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <button id="showOverlay" class="btn btn-default"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#showOverlay').click(function () {
                Modal.Loading();
            });
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is: whenever I clicked the button, nothing happens. But it works when I put the html element not inside `_Modal.cshtml` (Refer to the below code).

My question is: how can I get the class name in the `_Modal.cshtml` using JavaScript or JQuery?

I can do this in the `Modal.js` *(Note that it is same as I put that into _Modal.cshtml)* but that would be hard to maintain and I would like to put all of the content in the Partial View, and call it when needed by class name, instead of write string that will converted to JavaScript Object:

```
var loadingDiv = $('<div class="loadingOverlay"><button class="btn loading-button" disabled>'
        + '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-2x fa-fw"></i></button></div>');
```

Your answer much appreciated.

**Edit:**

Question on 31st of May 2016:

- What's the difference between `@Html.Partial("_Modal")` with `@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_Modal.cshtml")`. is it just to better understand for where the compiler get the partial views from?

Answered on 1st of June 2016 by @Guruprasad Rao:

- There is nothing difference between two except the mentioning of `partialview` name. The one I suggested was providing fully qualified path which helps compiler from where to fetch the `partialview`. To one you use will search in all the directories under the View folder. So the one I mentioned will be good in the aspect of performance.

Thanks for the @Guruprasad Rao for the answer and the explanation.

Cheers~

Comment: Did you include the `partialview` anywhere in the page? I don't see you have called it anywhere in the page..

Comment: No, i didn't include it anywhere in the page, I just create one cshtml and put everything in it, I thought if I call from JavaScript through html tag class name inside `partialview` and call it on the page, the JavaScript will contains same as the code above (html tags not in the `partialview`), thus the `partialview` will also be included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should import the `partialview` first from server to client browser first and then you can manipulate it with `jquery`. Otherwise there would be no `element` with the `selector` you are trying to find. User, `@Html.Partial` or `@Html.RenderPartial` to import it, hide it at initial state and show it on click. Take a below example:

```
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <button id="showOverlay" class="btn btn-default"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_Modal.cshtml")
  <!--I assume that the content inside this will be initially in hidden state-->

  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#showOverlay').click(function() {
        Modal.Loading();
      });
    })
  </script>
</body>
```

**Modal.js** changes

```
var Modal;

Modal = Modal || (function () {
    var loadingDiv = $('.loadingOverlay');
    return {
        Loading: function () {
            loadingDiv.css('display', 'block');
            //$('body').prepend(loadingDiv);
            //No need to prepend here since we are importing it through partial method
        },
        LoadingDismiss: function () {
            loadingDiv.fadeOut('500');
        },
    };
})();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot @Guruprasad Rao, just wondering is there any difference from: `@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_Modal.cshtml")` with `@Html.Partial("_Modal")` ?? or it is just to better understand where the compiler get the partial views from?

Comment: There is nothing difference between two except the mentioning of `partialview` name. The one I suggested was providing fully qualified path which helps compiler from where to fetch the `partialview`. To one you use will search in all the directories under the `View` folder. So the one I mentioned will be good in the aspect of performance..

Comment: Okay, it is more clearly now, thank you anyway and sorry for late reply @Guruprasad Rao. Cheers~ Btw, I have to reach 15 reputation before I upvote your comment >.<

Comment: Sorry buddy.. I mean you can upvote the answer instead of comment.. :) The up arrow mark beside my answer.. :)